# what the importance of function that return a value?

Tags: function, actionscript-3

i know function It is used to save time as repeated tasks . and We can pass an argument to the function to specify a value like this :

```
var myStar:Star;

function makeStar(myX:Number, myY:Number):void {
myStar = new Star();
myStar.x = myX;
myStar.y = myY;
addChild(myStar);
}

makeStar(50,50);
makeStar(150,150);
```

But my Question why i would like to use a function to return a number or string ... what the importance of that use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me ask you a Question: In your example code, how would you manipulate the first star you create to move, for example, 100 px to the right?

The answer is you can't (at least not in an easy way). You're overriding `myStar` with your second call to `makeStar(..)`.

Now, what would happen if `makeStar(..)` would return an Instance of `Star` instead of nothing?

Consider the following example:

```
var firstStar:Star;
var secondStar:Star;

function makeStar(_x:Number, _y:Number):Star
{
    var s = new Star();
    s.x = _x;
    s.y = _y;
    return s;
}

firstStar = makeStar(50, 150);
addChild(firstStar);
secondStar = makeStar(150, 150);
addChild(secondStar);

firstStar.x += 100;
secondStar.y += 100;
```

As you can see, now we can manipulate **both** stars, instead of only the last one you created.

---

To answer your question: You return values through functions so you can keep working with these values.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiousity, whats the disadvantage to this approach?

```
var myStar:Star;

function makeStar(myX:Number, myY:Number, Name:String):void {
    myStar = new Star();
    myStar.x = myX;
    myStar.y = myY;
    myStar.name = Name;
    addChild(myStar);
}

makeStar(50,50, "firstStar");
makeStar(150,150, "secondStar");



getChildByName("firstStar").x = 200;
```

Comment: That's not an answer to the question, that's a separate question. The disadvantage of this approach is speed, `getChildByName` will always be slower than using a reference, simply because it has to search the instance you're looking for. Imagine you have 100.000 Stars, and you want to manipulate star 65.432. Internally it will have to go through a search algorithm which will take up a considerable amount of time.